# Why can not use async response to generate template html in angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, directive

I want to implement a **like** widget for different kind of documents. I tried to use a scope data to generate template html code, here is what I've done:

```
  angular.module('app.common')
    .directive('like',['favoritesResource','session','$q', like]);

  function like(favoritesResource, session, $q, $scope) {

    var news = $q.defer();

    function link(scope, el) {
      //console.log(scope);
      news.resolve(scope.vm.theNews);
    };

    function getTemplate(el, attrs) {
      loadNews().then(function(news) {
        console.log(news);
        favoritesResource.isLike(session.getCurrentUser.id, {docType: news.type, docId: news.id}, function(status) {
          if (status == 'like'){
            return '<button class="fa fa-heart" ng-click="vm.likeIt()">like</button>';
          }else {
            return '<button class="fa fa-heart-o" ng-click="vm.likeIt()">like</button>'
          }
        });
      });
    };

    function loadNews() {
      return news.promise;
    }

    return {
      link: link,
      restrict: 'E',
      template: getTemplate(),
      replace: true
    };
  }
```

I found the "news" object can be printed in the console, but the result html is `<like></like>`, not `<button class="fa fa-heart" ng-click="vm.likeIt()">unlike</button>` or `<button class="fa fa-heart-o" ng-click="vm.likeIt()">like</button>`, could anyone tell me what's wrong? Or do you have any suggestion to write such widget?

**UPDATE**:

This widget is within a controller used to show document content, here is my controller:

```
  angular
    .module('app.news')
    .controller('ReadNewsController', ReadNewsController);

  ReadNewsController.$inject = ['theNews', '$scope', 'favoritesResource', 'session'];
  function ReadNewsController(theNews, $scope, favoritesResource, session) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.theNews = theNews;

    vm.likeIt = function() {
      favoritesResource.like(session.getCurrentUser.id, {docType:theNews.type, docId: theNews.id});
    };

    vm.unlikeIt = function() {
      favoritesResource.disLike(session.getCurrentUser.id, {docType:theNews.type, docId: theNews.id});
    };

    vm.isLikeIt = function() {
      favoritesResource.isLike(session.getCurrentUser.id, {docType:theNews.type, docId: theNews.id});
    };
  }
```

and the routes:

```
var module = angular.module('app.news', ['ui.router', 'app.common', 'app.data']);

  module.config(appConfig);

  appConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

  function appConfig($stateProvider) {.state('app.readNews', {
        url: '/news/read/:id',
        templateUrl: 'app/modules/news/read/news.html',
        controller: 'ReadNewsController as vm',
        resolve: {
          theNews: function(newsResource, $stateParams) {
            return newsResource.get({id: $stateParams.id}).$promise.then(function(item){
              item.type = 'news'; //for 'like' directive
              return item;
            })
          }
        }
      })
```

Comment: The `getTemplate()` method returns before the function in the `then()` function gets executed since it is asynchronous.

Comment: the only difference I see is in class.. you should use ng-class value.. it can change it dynamically based on response of `.then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much much simpler to add conditional logic to the template using `ng-class`. Then load the data and set the scope variable `isLiked`

```
function like() {

    return {
      link: link,
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<button class="fa" ng-class="{\'fa-heart\': isLiked,\'fa-heart-o\': !isLiked }" ng-click="vm.likeIt()">like</button>',
      replace: true
    };
  }

 function link(scope, el) {
  loadNews().then(function(news) {

    favoritesResource.isLike(session.getCurrentUser.id, {docType: news.type, docId: news.id}, function(status) {
        scope.isLiked = status === 'like'
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: it should not work because isLiked is not exist when "template" is used.

Comment: that doesn't make sense ... you are going to use the same api call as you were to check which template and you can always set default to false

Comment: @eric2323223 The way the `ng-class` directive works is that it puts a `$watch` on the scope looking for `isLiked`. When `isLiked` changes (or becomes defined), the `ng-class` modifies the class of the element. @charlietfl is right. `ng-class` is the best way to do what you want.

Comment: I get this error using charlietfl's code:   Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'ng' is an unexpected token at column 47 of the expression [{'fa-heart': isLiked,'fa-heart-o': !isLiked } ng-click=] starting at [ng-click=].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/$parse/syntax?p0=ng&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=47&p3=%7B'fa-heart'%3ANaNsLiked%2C'fa-heart-o'%3A%20!isLiked%20%7D%20ng-click%3D&p4=ng-click%3D

Comment: The reason of the error is it miss a ", it works now. Thank you guys.

Comment: sorry about missing quote.